# Dividing an image into Irregular Regions

Tags: c, image-processing

I have a face image of 800*600. I want to divide it into different non-rectangular regions like one region for left eye, one for right eye, and so on.
I basically want to design a code - "Given (x,y) coordinate, in which region it lie." 
How to do this??

Comment: Which part is the problem? Is the problem deciding where the regions are? Or are you doing that by hand? Or is the problem working out how to mark/label/identify the regions for the user? Or have you done all that and you now want to know which region is being clicked? Is this a web-based application, or just running on local desktop? Are you on Linux, OSX or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV. It has simple functions for eye detecting and it's free.

**Read these material:**

http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/eye-detection-and-tracking/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23191/Face-and-Eyes-Detection-Using-OpenCV

[Read this pdf](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FMahdi_Rezaei6%2Fpublication%2F259584297_Face_and_Eye_Detection_Using_OpenCV_Step_by_Step%2Flinks%2F02e7e52ccb063c069d000000.pdf&ei=cmTcVL2JGoX4yQTsu4CQDg&usg=AFQjCNFNz_Uf8Ttz6RuGzhxhL6WaWuxfeg&sig2=2Oc1jXLs101nj4plYgE95g&bvm=bv.85761416,d.aWw&cad=rja)